# Cleaning text to strip [] and "" in julia dataframe

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I have a dataframe with a column `text` that a is a list of strings, like this:

```
 text
```

["text1","text2"]
["text3","text4"]

How can I clean de string to have another column `text_clean` like this:

```
text
```

text1,text2
text3,text4

When I type in repl `df` I get:

```
text
String
["string"]
["string","anotherestring"]
```

but when I type:

```
df[!,:text]
```

I get:

```
"[\"string\"]"
"[\"string\",\anotherestring\"]"
```

I would like to create a new dolumn, called `text_clean`:

```
string
string, anotherstring
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify: is it that you currently have a column with Arrays of strings, and you wish to join each array into a single comma-separated string? It would be useful if you could just post the output of `df["text"]` from your REPL (where `df` is the name of your dataframe).

Answer (score 1):

```
julia> a = [["text", "text2"], ["text"], ["text", "text2", "text", "text2"]]
3-element Vector{Vector{String}}:
 ["text", "text2"]
 ["text"]
 ["text", "text2", "text", "text2"]

julia> join.(a, ",")
3-element Vector{String}:
 "text,text2"
 "text"
 "text,text2,text,text2"
```

replace a with your column, like `df.text`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your strings literally have values containing `[`s, `"`s, etc.

First of all, make sure that this is intended. For eg., you might have something like a `vec = ["string", "anotherstring"]`. At some point before this, you might have code doing the equivalent of `df[1, :text] = string(vec)`. Instead, do `df[1, :text] = join(vec, ", ")` when assigning to the `text` column, to have that original column itself be clean.

If the above doesn't apply, and you have to deal with the column as given, then you create your new cleaned column like this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(:text => [string(["hello", "world"]), string(["this","is","SPARTA"])])
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ text                     
     │ String                   
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │ ["hello", "world"]
   2 │ ["this", "is", "SPARTA"]

julia> df[!, :text_clean] = map(df.text) do str
       str |>
        s -> strip(s, ('[', ']')) |>  #remove [ ]
        s -> strip.(split(s, ", "), '"') |>  # remove inner "
        sv -> join(sv, ", ")
       end
2-element Vector{String}:
 "hello, world"
 "this, is, SPARTA"
```

(You might have to adjust the second argument to `split` above based on whether or not you have a space after the commas in the `text` column.)

Or, making use of Julia's own syntax parsing,

```
julia> df[!, :text_clean] = map(df.text) do str
        str |> Meta.parse |>
               ex -> ex.head == :vect && eval(ex) |>
               sv -> join(sv, ", ")

       end
2-element Vector{String}:
 "hello, world"
 "this, is, SPARTA"
```

(The `ex.head == :vect` is a basic sanity check to make sure that the string is in the format you expect, and not anything malicious, before `eval`uating it.)